# Where can I download MS-LOGO officially?

Tags: command-line

Need to download MS-LOGO for school kid.

I am trying to avoid 3rd party softwares: since they often come with virus or malicious codes.

Contacted Microsoft but they were unable to provide that software.

Any alternative LOGO with Command line interface will be acceptable but it has to be

- using Same commands as MS LOGO
- Offline
- Runs in Windows
- Preferably have black background and White pen-line.

Answer (score 3):

According to my 2-minute research, the original software is not called MS-LOGO, but "MSW-LOGO". The original software has nothing to do with Microsoft, I think. it was developed George Mills and Brian Harvey at MIT and University of California Berkeley.

The original website at https://softronix.com/logo.html does host downloads. In case those doesn't work anymore, you may try the github-clone of the source code and a build version at https://github.com/Hobadee/MSW-Logo

Answer (score 2):

It's been years since I've researched LOGO, but there are some interesting projects around it still alive.

If you're ok with an online alternative, take a look at

> https://www.calormen.com/jslogo/

This one is 'LOGO in a browser', with samples. Might be an easy to share resource with students.

Although not a 'straight answer', I've started with that because of its **Links** section which points to several other resources, including some downloadable ones.

One of those downloadable options is Barkeley Logo (UCBLogo) at

> https://github.com/jrincayc/ucblogo-code
> With their main page at
> [https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/logo.html](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ebh/logo.html)
> The project seems rather active (last commit less than 2 months ago), latest release was December 2020 (less than 10 months ago)

There are a few other very cool resources on that page as well.

Answer (score 0):

At first, I thought you meant MS Logo, as in the windows icon.

Upon researching a little, this sounds a lot like the "turtle graphics" I used as a kid on my parent's old Atari.  [There's a python library now that does turtle graphics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html).  Because it's python-based, there's also a ton of tutorials for it online.  It's also cross-platform, so it should work on windows, linux, or mac products.

Answer (score 0):

UCB LOGO from UC Barkeley solves my purpose.